# C++11 get all items of one bucket in a unordered_map

Tags: c++11, unordered-map

we know `std::unordered_map::bucket` return A bucket is a slot in the container's internal hash table to which elements are assigned based on the hash value of their key. How can I get the begin-iterator and end-iterator in the return bucket ? In other word, I can use `bucket_count` to get count of buckets, how can detect items in each bucket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [std::unordered_map::begin(int)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/begin2) and [std::unordered_map::end(int)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/end2) to get iterators for a particular bucket.

Comment: the return is a `std::__detail::_Local_iterator`, will the `classname::iterator` type is `std::__detail::_Node_iterator` can be access the item through  the local_iterrator directly?

Comment: The local_iterator can be used in the same way as a normal iterator. The "first" parameter will give you the key and the "second" parameter will give you the value. E.g. `iter->first; iter->second`. [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/begin/) page gives an example.

Comment: so this two iterator can't cast ot each other? It is different with SGI hash_map iterator.

Comment: No, you can't cast between the two. As mentioned before though you can get the values from a local_iterator in just the same way as an iterator.